# how to create parameter in ssrs with hard code value yes and No

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi i am creating a report using SSRS and i am getting value for this report from a store procedure; now i'd like to create a parameter which should have only YES and NO values in the drop down list. Base on this value when i should select YES  i want a new column to be added inside the report with data and when i should select NO that column should disappear.

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parameter `p_costcentre` with available values as `Yes` and `No` and based on the parameter selected value set the column visibility of the column `Cost Centre` as : `iif(Parameters!p_costcentre.value = "Yes",false,true)`.

Comment: what should be the data type of parameter?

Comment: keep data type as text

Comment: Glad to know that :)